# Two tableViews in one View Controller issue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am implementing two separate tableViews in a viewController.One of them is loaded on a button click.This table View loads up but doesn't show cell contents.However on second click it shows the contents.What is the correct way to do this?

This is how I am loading the tableView on button click event.

```
- (IBAction)barButtonClicked:(id)sender {
     aTableView=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,25 ,200, 150)];
     aTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
     aTableView.delegate=self;
     aTableView.dataSource=self;
     [[KGModal sharedInstance]showWithContentView:aTableView andAnimated:YES];
 }
```

This is how I am configuring the tableViews.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
     if (tableView.tag==0){.....}
     else if (tableView==aTableView) {

     UIButton *seeButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
     seeButton.frame=CGRectMake(20, 20, 60, 20);
     [seeButton setTitle:@"Show contents" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [cell.contentView addSubview:seeButton];
     cell.textLabel.text = [tempArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];//After scrolling the table view...crash occurs  here.
}

return cell;
}
```

Comment: I would remove this statement `if (tableView==aTableView)` and replace with a tag for the aTableView. If you use tags, why don't tag both tableViews? If I would approach this from the begining, I would load both tableView in viewDidLoad, set aTableView hidden, and then on a button click unhide it with animation.

Answer (score 0):

try to force reload data in your barButtonClicked:

```
[aTableView reloadData];
```